# How to set inheritance in golang

Tags: inheritance, go

## tl;dr

What is the right way to set `Store` to be shared between multiple services in this example: https://github.com/th0th/goblog/blob/2b2d7ac51978de41f392396309424043817a49d7/store/store.go#L29

## Details

Greetings, I am trying to comprehend how go works by creating a simple MVC-ish blog REST API. I have planned the application to consist of 3 packages/layers:

#### models

Holds the structs of data. Defines the interfaces for database access layers of these structs.

#### store

Presents the actual database connections. Implements the interfaces from models. All database access is done through this implementation.

#### api

REST API related stuff. Routes and such.

I have a `Store` struct in `store` package, which holds the services:

```
// Store wraps all services
type Store struct {
    DB *sqlx.DB

    CategoryService CategoryService
    PostService PostService
}
```

And here is the `CategoryService` (`PostService` is also like this. They both have methods for CRUD actions.):

```
// CategoryService represents a service for managing categories.
type CategoryService struct {
    store *Store
}
```

When I create an instance of this `Store`, I need to set store of every single service.

```
// New creates and returns new Store
func New() Store {
    var s Store

    db, err := sqlx.Connect("mysql", "<user>:<pass>@(localhost:3306)/goblog")

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    s.DB = db

    s.CategoryService.store = &s
    s.PostService.store = &s

    return s
}
```

I want store to be shared between services, what is the correct approach? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I tried to share all required details about the question. I'd be awesome if you can just share why you down vote.

Comment: Go doesn't have inheritance. So it's impossible to set it.

Comment: If you got what I am trying to accomplish, what would be the right way?

Answer (score 2):

I find a bit strange in your design that the `Store` knows about the services and the services know about the `Store`...to me that double dependency does not look right, but that's probably subject to debate.

If I were you, I would remove the services from the `Store` and pass the `Store` as parameter when you create the each service.

For example, remove the services from the store:

```
type Store struct {
  DB *sqlx.DB
  // no services here
}
```

...and pass the `Store` as a parameter when you create the service:

```
type CategoryService struct {
  store *Store
}

func NewCategoryService(s Store) CategoryService {
  var service CategoryService
  service.store = s
  return service
}

func (service CategoryService) Add()  {
  // service will have access to the store value
  // via service.store
}
```

Comment: I was thinking of making all database layer accessible when `Store` is created. So if multiple services are to be used, I don't have to initiate one by one. Why is it wrong?

Comment: I don't think what you are trying to do is wrong. But as a matter of preference I would rather have only one component know about the other (e.g. the Services know about the Store and keep the Store independent of the Services).